# Angular 6 post prefixing http://localhost:4200/

Tags: angular6

I am trying to post a JSON file to a RESTful endpoint, but the request always prefixes "http://localhost:4200" to it.

Code:

`app.component.ts`

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: './app.component.css'
})

export class AppComponent {
  private _url = 'website.com';
  private _url2 = './assets/data/rfdata2.json';

  public newGet = this.http.post(this._url, this._url2);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.newGet.subscribe(data => this.getArray = data);
  }
}
```

`./assets/data/rfdata2.json`

```
[
  {"frequency":2440.000, "name": "sig1", "id": "{mf0382mf4q8392-28nm3fq- q2u389mqf}"},
  {"frequency":2460.000, "name": "sig2", "id": "{39n893-48398anjh9n8na-0398wnf}"},
  {"frequency":2480.000, "name": "sig3", "id": "{fanb8903y84-may7md9a387kfa7m8}"}
]
```

`Error text`

```
ERROR Object { headers: Object, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/website.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://we…", error: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <h…" }
```

(Obviously, website.com isn't the real endpoint. Just using it as a placeholder for my real website)

I also get the same error with a GET request. How do I get it to NOT prefix "http://localhost:4200/" to the POST URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a protocol to your URL.

`private _url = 'https://website.com';`

Comment: Oh duh, I should have noticed that. Thanks!